# TFSBuild, execute Selenium UI Tests on being built code before deploy

Tags: .net, selenium, mstest, tfsbuild, functional-testing

I've a set of Selenium tests using the C# WebDriver and MSTest (Visual Studio Test).

Hopefully, I could integrate these tests successfully and they're working as expected.

Sadly, I found a big problem: the automated UI tests are executed against the previously deployed solution, so if previous build was successful, the test run will pass, and a bugged deploy can happen.

Perhaps I can have a different Web site to pre-deploy the solution before the tests are executed, something like http://test.mydomain.com and execute the UI tests against this, and if nothing goes wrong with the test run, then the same site could be deployed to the production Web site.

In summary, do you know any other better approach for solving this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes, this is how we have done it too. We have nightly Selenium tests but when releasing, we use a powershell script which packages up our code (for Azure), but also deploys the latest version to a test website and then triggers a TeamCity build. Unfortunately I don't know TFS that well!

Comment: @Arran Hey, thank you for your information. Team City or TFS, it's almost the same problem! Your info/opinion is still useful, why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is an excellent solution, and one which is in common use. Depending on exactly what you use the pre-deploy server for and how it fits into your overall development/deployment process, you might refer to it as a *test server* or *[staging server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_site)*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sometimes the solution is "others do the same solution"! Actually I already have a staging server. Maybe it's time to use it like your suggestion, you're right!